# Google compute network load balancing health checks are failing

Tags: load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I have debian instances with nginx on 80 port. Firewall rules allow 80 port :

```
Source Ranges: 0.0.0.0/0
Allowed Protocols or Ports: tcp:80
```

GCE health checks are failing for that instances while curl correctly returns a 200 OK response.

On those instances i have installed upstart instead of default System V init.
Could it be related?! Are there any special services that should be running on the instance to get health check working?!

Here is the instance tcpdump output showing there is no ack flags coming from load balancer (169.254.169.254 as described [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#update_firewall_rules)) :

```
19:13:20.513882 IP 169.254.169.254.49291 > 130.211.125.185.80: Flags [S], seq 503850, win 8096, options [mss 1024], length 0
19:13:23.016788 IP 169.254.169.254.49291 > 130.211.125.185.80: Flags [S], seq 503850, win 8096, options [mss 1024], length 0
19:13:26.017750 IP 169.254.169.254.49291 > 130.211.125.185.80: Flags [S], seq 503850, win 8096, options [mss 1024], length 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you changed the init daemon, it is very probable your problem is related to google-address-manager script not running.  You can try to start the process manually or adding the ip address of the load balancer as described in [Google Compute Engine health checks failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937469/google-compute-engine-health-checks-failing).